# $\left|\sum_{i=1}^Nf(x-i)\right|^2\leq C\sum_{i=1}^N|f(x-i)|^2$ for all $N$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics

It is elementary to show that 
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^Nf(x-i)\right|^2\leq N\sum_{i=1}^N|f(x-i)|^2$$
for any function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and any $x\in\mathbb R$ (in fact this holds for any sequence of real numbers $a_i$ which do not have to be of the form $a_i=f(x-i)$).

My question is for which class of functions the above inequality holds *without the N on the right-hand side*, i.e.
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^Nf(x-i)\right|^2\leq C\sum_{i=1}^N|f(x-i)|^2,\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb R$$
for some $C>0$ independent of $N$ and $x$.
 It is clear that such functions include functions with compact support, but surely the class is larger than this.

Experiments with Maple seem to suggest that such an inequality is still true for functions decaying exponentially, but fails to hold for functions decaying polynomially.

Comment: What is the role of $x$ here? Can you write your statement more clearly? The constant $C$ should depend on $x$ or not?

Comment: why would the compactly supported functions satisfy that? (They are dense in the measurable functions, aren't they?)

Comment: Sorry, I really wasn't very clear. C should not depend on x.

Comment: For compactly supported functions, there is at most finite number of $k$ such that $f(x-k)\neq 0$ and this number does not depend on $x$, right?

Comment: Right. And the idea is that if the function decays fast enough, one can still obtain essentially the samt thing. I just can't come up with an idea for a proof

Comment: For $C=N$, it becomes Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plateaus (intervals where function is constant) of length L exist, then C needs to be at least $ L $. No decay assumption on the function will prevent arbitrarily long plateaus. Neither will any translation invariant space such as Sobolev spaces. You'd need for example a space whose norm includes a weighted derivative with weights growing at infinity.

Comment: The constant isn't supposed to be independent of $f$, only of $x$ and $N$.

Comment: I know. But what my post says is that for a single $ f $ you won't be able to get such a constant. Because a single function will be able to have different plateaus of increasing lengths (and decreasing heights)

Comment: @Frank consider for example the function that has value $2^{-2^k} $ on the interval $[2^k,2^{k+1}]$. It is in all Levesque spaces (it even decays exponentially fast), yet it has no such constant as looking at $ x=2^k, N=2^k $ reveals

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. Your example gives $C=2^k$, right?
Thanks, this was really enlightening.
It still troubles me that the inequality seems to be valid for $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$ though (by numerical experiments). There must be some criterion that makes the statament true...

Comment: Yes, looking at a single $x=2^k$ and $n=2^k$ shows that $C\geq 2^k$; thus, there is no univeral $C$ that works for all $x$ and $N$